# Unity Create Room Error

Tags: unity, multiplayer

I get the following error

> “NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object”

I have updated it by adding extra arguments but I still get that issue. Below is my code, the issue is on the final line.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class Host : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private uint roomSize = 8;
private string roomName;
private NetworkManager networkManager;

void start () {
    networkManager = NetworkManager.singleton;
    if (networkManager.matchMaker == null) {
        networkManager.StartMatchMaker();
    }
}

public void SetRoomName (string _name) {
    roomName = _name;
}

public void CreateRoom() {
    if (roomName != “” && roomName != null) {
        Debug.Log (“Creating Room: ” + roomName + ” with room for ” + roomSize + ” players.”);
        networkManager.matchMaker.CreateMatch(roomName, roomSize, true, “”, “”, “”, 0, 0, networkManager.OnMatchCreate);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your start-method isn't executed because you spelled it wrong. It's `void Start ()`, not `void start()`.